# What is wrong with this Google Chrome context menu?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, context-menu

I expect my chrome context menu to be like the following:

[image]

However, my menu is like this:

[image]

See the missing Tasks area? What is the reason for this? Would re-installing fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/fjCZgoQxui0) discussion topic, it was removed in Chrome 21.

However, the topic linked at the end of that one suggests the following [fix](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/AHb_wGvJGV8):

> Right click on "Start" menu > Properties > Check "Store and display recently opened items in the Start menu and the taskbar" option. 
>   Click "OK" to accept the changes, wait a few seconds and that's it!
>   You should have your right click options back.